# Load html page into div inside canvas container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Edit : This is the console error -  jquery.min.js:2 Failed to load file:///root/Documents/VS%20Code/Javascript/MockDashboard/hr.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I am creating a dashboard using css libraries like slidebar js & bootstrap. It seems that everything is correct except that I am not able to load an html page from the off-canvas sidebar link to a canvas div. Kindly help me with my code :

```js
$("#hr").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#body").load('./hr.html');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slidebars.min.css">    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/slidebars.min.js"></script>

<div canvas="container">

  <!-- Top Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
  </nav>

  <!-- Body -->
  <div class="container" id="body">
  </div>

  <!-- Bottom Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-bottom">
  </nav>

</div>


<!-- Slidebar -->
<div off-canvas="id-1 left overlay">
  <div class="container-fluid sidebar">

    <div class="jumbotron sidebar-profile">
      <a href="profile.html" class="dp-click">
        <img src="css/default-dp.png" class="img-circle dp" alt="dp">
      </a>
      <h4 class="username">Anon</h4>
    </div>

  <a href="hr.html" id="hr">HR</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What's the problem you want us to solve?

Comment: @JBDouble05 Nothing happens on clicking HR link on the slidebar. "hr.html" does not load on the main page between the navbars.

Comment: see what the data returned by the complete callback says. It might be not be able to find that page http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Maybe the browser is going to `hr.html` and then returning because it realises there's a function being called.

Comment: Also check the browser console for errors. Maybe you are executing the script block before you are loading the jQuery library

Comment: @KScandrett On the console I get this error : jquery.min.js:2 Failed to load file:///root/Documents/VS%20Code/Javascript/MockDashboard/hr.html: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: The page is also present in the main directory "MockDashboard". So how exactly must i fix this error?

Comment: Thank you all. I solved the problem. The answer is typed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: Chrome does not allow you to make AJAX requests using the file: protocol if the page was loaded using the file: protocol. So this same code works perfectly on firefox. If anyone figures out a way to make it work on chrome, please update the answer.